# What is the usage of JavaScript in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning bootstrap. As I can see, it is pretty straight forward to use it. I tried to use the framework without including any reference to the JavaScript files and it is working just fine (at basic level).

So my question is - can I just ignore the JavaScript files and use only the css-based grid system, or the css depends on JavaScript in some way and I just don't face it now.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need JS just don't use it. If eventually you need it, then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need anything from [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) page you can skip loading the javascript asset.

Answer (score 1):

YES, If you do not need any javascript related component (modal,tab etc.) ,
Also please remember you could customize entire framework with link below:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Just check what you want and download.